# Can we use Credit-Control-Failure-Handling AVP in Gx interface

Tags: diameter-protocol

Will it be possible to use Credit-Control-Failure-Handling AVP in Gx interface.
If PCRF goes down or due to network problem, so will it be possible that PCEF can use a Credit-Control-Failure-Handling AVP to try the failover. Is this an allowed behavior in Gx-Interface as per 3GPP Standards.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Underlying SCTP layer carrying the Diameter traffic can take care of the Failover, where multi-homed SCTP path and session failure detection mechanisms (Heartbeat) can actively monitor the connectivity of the session and if there is any failure it can automatically choose the alternate path.

Answer (score 0):

Credit-Control-Failure-Handling is applicable to Gy Interface only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).